# Trying to access previous record in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, calculated-columns

I'm trying to do a balance column in a accounting app with c# winforms, i'm doing it just for using by myself, being the formula of that column like this one:

```
balance[i] = debit[i] - credit[i] + balance[i-1]
```

So, I thought a calculated column would be the best solution. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Community and SQL Server, I tried to do it in the "table view" in the `CREATE TABLE` script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CONTAT1] 
(
    [NASIENTO] INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [FECHA]    DATE           NOT NULL,
    [CONCEPTO] NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [DEBIT]     INT            DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [CREDIT]    INT            DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [BALANCE]    AS             ([DEBIT]-[CREDIT] + lag([BALANCE], 1, 0)),
    [FACTURA]  INT            NULL,
    [RECIBO]   INT            NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([NASIENTO] ASC)
);
```

I specified the default lag's parameter so in the first record the function lag just add 0 (oh, I've translated the so-called rows names so anyone can follow the question). When i update the table it don't work and gives the following message:

```
Dropping unnamed constraint on [dbo].[CONTAT1]...
Dropping unnamed constraint on [dbo].[CONTAT1]...
Starting rebuilding table [dbo].[CONTAT1]...
(116,1): SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 10753, Level 15, State 1, Line 13 The function 'lag' must have an OVER clause.
(104,0): SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;

SET XACT_ABORT ON;

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tmp_ms_xx_CONTAT1] (
    [NASIENTO] INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [FECHA]    DATE           NOT NULL,
    [CONCEPTO] NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [DEBIT]     INT            DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [CREDIT]    INT            DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [BALANCE]    AS             ([DEBIT] - [CREDIT] + lag([BALANCE], 1, 0)),
    [FACTURA]  INT            NULL,
    [RECIBO]   INT            NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([NASIENTO] ASC)
);

IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1
           FROM   [dbo].[CONTAT1])
    BEGIN
        SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tmp_ms_xx_CONTAT1] ON;
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[tmp_ms_xx_CONTAT1] ([NASIENTO], [FECHA], [CONCEPTO], [DEBIT], [CREDIT], [FACTURA], [RECIBO])
    SELECT   [NASIENTO],
             [FECHA],
             [CONCEPTO],
             [DEBIT],
             [CREDIT],
             [FACTURA],
             [RECIB
An error occurred while the batch was being executed.
```

The last time I used SQL was like in the early 2000's, so I'm not sure why don't work... honestly, the batch thing is killing me.

I have searched the lag function and seems correct to me, and since the table have a primary key AND if I just try it without the lag function (using just `[BALANCE] AS ([DEBIT]-[CREDIT])`  ) it works perfectly, I suppose I have no need to specify the order or something else, so I suppose again the problem is the lag function.

The questions are:

The lag function can be used with `CREATE TABLE`, right? And if not, should i just make a query in the form OnLoad event to create that column?

Are there any other way to access the previous record? Yes, i could do it via DataSet with a very simple foreach, but i don't want to create... how do you call it in english? Gaps? Just different information in the database and the app, and duplicate queries and what not... so i thought it would be better that the database manage it automagically :P , right?

Comment: Sorry SQL tables don't have a guaranteed natural order.  For this reason you cannot include LAG or LEAD in the definition of a computed column.  You could create a view that sits on top of the table, and includes the balance calc.  This works because you can now access the ORDER BY clause, which is the only way you can enforce order on a SQL set.

Comment: What **VERSION** of SQL Server are you using? `LAG` and `LEAD` are **new features** in SQL Server **2012**, if you have an earlier version (verify by running `SELECT @@VERSION`) you're out of luck ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no previous record in SQL - tables have no order.

Standard for accounting - and in most jurisdictions even legally quite required - is to record the change AND THE NEW VALUE in the table, together with a running number (per account).

Comment: I know tables generally have no order in SQL, but doesn't the key solve that? I thought that since the lag function exists. Sorry, edit: i didn't understand what do you mean by record the change and the new value, what does that have to do with the computed column?

Comment: What is has to do is that this value is NOT COMPUTED. Only beginners make this mistake. Keep the value not on the transaction but the account AND on the transaction, but not as computed column.

Comment: @Nox *"I know tables generally have no order in SQL"* > No, tables **DO NOT** have an order in SQL. Resultsets can be ordered though using an `ORDER BY` clause

Comment: I would apreciate it if you would treat me as a beginner, since as i said in the question, i have not used SQL for like 15 years (and any other language to be honest). So the thing is that i shouldn't do it with a computed column, then wouldn't it be easier just to calculate it outside the database and just store the results?

Comment: It is not about easier. It is about (a) performance (you may have TONS of transactions and calculating the current value would take time) and auditability (accounting has high requirements).

Comment: Btw., you may want to read up on the legal side. When I did my first accounting system years ago, there was a document my tax advisor gave me that contained guidelines for computer based accounting systems ;) Was very helpful.

Comment: @TomTom Ok, i'll search for it, ty!